# How to use WSAAsyncSelect from WinAPI in C#?

Tags: c#, winapi, callback, winsock, wsaasyncselect

I'm tired of the .NET BeginRead,EndRead stuff.I'd love to use WSAAsyncSelect the way I used to in Delphi/C++

```
//Async CallBack handler Declaration
procedure MessageHandler(var Msg:Tmessage);Message WM_WINSOCK_ASYNC_MSG;

//Where i setup the Async
dwError := WSAAsyncSelect(Sock, form1.handle, WM_WINSOCK_ASYNC_MSG, FD_CLOSE or FD_READ);

//Async Callback Handler
procedure Tform1.MessageHandler(var Msg:Tmessage);
begin
  case WSAGetSelectEvent(MSG.LParam) of //LParam is FD_READ/FR_CLOSE/FD_WRITE
    FD_READ: OnSocketRead(MSG.WParam); //WPARAM is the Socket itself.
    FD_CLOSE: OnSocketClose(MSG.WParam);
  end;
end;
```

Is it possible to set that event in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could use [`SocketAsyncEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx) in the same pattern.